# Interactive Python Dashboard Without Server Deployment or Running Code

Tags: python, deployment, visualization, dashboard

I would like to create a dashboard for users without requiring them to run code or access a server.  Therefore, web-based applications do not work. I've explored options like using Jupyter Notebooks with nbconvert, voila, and panel; and while these solutions offer some level of interactivity, they still involve the user running commands locally.  Of course, I can create a static HTML version of the dashboard, but this will not be interactive.

Ideally, I would create a set of files that could be shared with users who could then access the dashboard.  Is this possible?  Or is there some other way to create a dynamic and interactive Python dashboard that users can access without running any code or accessing a web-based application?

Comment: Read [my reply here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/use-online-version-of-jupyter/22802/2?u=fomightez) in response to a similar question. You'll be particularly interested in using MyBinder to serve Voila apps. GitHub pages are nice for using in conjunction with Voici. Oh wait, I see now you are trying for not web-based. There is supposed to be a potable, distributable version of Voici in the works; however, that is probably further out then you need now. There is Jupyter Desktop. Also see ...

Comment: <continued>[How do you share notebooks? Best practices around sharing to external stakeholders?](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-do-you-share-notebooks-best-practices-around-sharing-to-external-stakeholders/3617?u=fomightez). It is a few years old now but some of the ideas have evolved there to be better, especially Jupyter Books which has spawned the related Myst. You also may be interested in [Mercury](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/mercury-convert-notebook-to-web-app-with-yaml-header-and-share-with-others/12562/3?u=fomightez). Or possibly ....

Comment: <continued> [ContainDS or Renku](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/creating-a-new-binder-at-home-tool/431/14?u=fomightez). Keep in mind though that those suggestions above tend to get farther away from the developing Jupyter ecosystem as a I wrote from top to bottom and so the active development/support may be more tentative in the later ones.

Comment: I should have added that for using the MyBinder route, you can potentially just make a repo that installs the needed software and then distribute the notebook to the stakeholders directly. Then instruct them how to launch in the JupyterLab interface, drop in the notebook file in the panel on the left, double click to open the notebook in that panel, and then press the Voila button icon along the toolbar at the top in the sessions. Yes, it is a few steps but it can be explained as uploading to a remote computer. You can actually have them save the updates back to local machine often. You ...

Comment: <comment> try an example along the lines this by clicking [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb) and imagine they had already uploaded the notebook that will open there. This makes it easier to not share the notebook online but use a public service if that is an issue.